# Laravel 5 - Override Get or Select from Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to override the **->get()** methods from Eloquent in order to always customize the output of the selected fields from the DB query?

For example, if you do a usual Eloquent query like:

```
User::where('email','like','%wherever.com')->get();
```

Instead of it making the query:

```
Select name, email, address, created_at from users where email like '%wherever.com'
```

Is it possible to override the method to always return something like:

```
Select CONCAT('CL::',name), lower(email), address, created_at from users where email like '%wherever.com'
```

I ask for ->get because I have seen that I can pass an array with the columns to be selected but I don't want to define them on all queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after digging around the functions regarding the query I found this solution:

I created a new class **CustomQueryBuilder** that extends the **Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder**

There you can override the **get() / select() / where()** methods from Eloquent.

Then, in the models that you want to change the way the query is made, define the fields to change like:

```
protected $encrypted = [
    'name',
    'email',

];
```

After this, I created a new class **CustomModel** that extends the **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model** and there override the **newBaseQueryBuilder** like this:

```
protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();

    return new CustomQueryBuilder(
        $connection, $connection->getQueryGrammar(), $connection->getPostProcessor(), $this
    );
}
```

Inside the **CustomQueryBuilder** you can customise all the methods from builder for your needs.

With this setup, you can in any **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model** change it to extend your **CustomModel** and inherit this special behaviour for the designated columns.

Be aware that all queries made from Models extending your CustomModel will get this new methods, so do all the needed checks to don't mess up with Eloquent normal behaviour, something like this:

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{

    if ($this->model !== null && isset($this->model::$encrypted)) 
    {
        if (in_array($column, $this->model::$encrypted)) 
        {
            $column = DB::raw("CONCAT('CL::',$column)");
        }
    }

    parent::where($column, $operator, $value, $boolean);

}
```

PS: I know this sound silly with the CONCAT example but with the property $encrypted you can figure out that it's not for concatenating string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use model to update the result for the specific field like below

Use this code in your model file to contact `CL::' with the`name` value

```
public function getNameAttribute($value) {
        return 'CL::'.$value;
    }
```

You can just call `User::where('email','like','%wherever.com')->get();` like this

This `getNameAttribute` function will always return name value with "CL::"

So you don't need to add `CONCAT('CL::'.name)` with your query.

Same way you can add for other fields also

---

**Updated**
Solution when querying the result

Add this `geofields` in your model

```
protected $geofields = array("concat('CL::',name) as name");
```

Add this `newQuery` function to override the columns

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        $raw='';
        foreach($this->geofields as $column){
            $raw .= $column;
        }

        return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)->addSelect('*',\DB::raw($raw));
    }
```

Hope this is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Hari, but if you do that, you can only modify the data after querying the database, my intention is to modify the data on his root, on the query, not after querying. The concat function is only an example, what I really want to do is a decrypt but the usage can be the same

Comment: You are correct. but this example is to ignore the `concat` in each query.
if you want the data on his root you need to do the `concat` with your query.I don't think there is other way.

Comment: But that's not what was asked. I need to always send the **concat**, without defining it on every query, so I believe that if I override the select to change the columns or if I'm able to modify the get that also accepts the columns, this problem is solved, I just can't find how to extend Eloquent or override his methods

Comment: Let me check the solution for that

Comment: Thanks Hari, your suggestion is also good and you pointed me in the right direction, I already found my solution, I will answer the question with all clear for future reference and for someone that arrive here with the same problem as me. Thanks.