# Overriding Laravel get and first methods

Tags: laravel

I need to override above mentioned methods to skip some database records. Using `where` is not an option since I would have to use it every single time as there are records in database that I do not need most of the time and I am not allowed to delete them from DB. Here is my attempt of doing this:

```php
class SomeTable extends BaseModel { 

    public static function first() {
       $query = static::query();
       $data = $query->first();
       if($data && $data->type == 'migration_type') return null;

       return $data;
    }

    public static function get() {
       $query = static::query();
       $data = $query->get();
       foreach($data as $key => $item) {
           if($item->type == 'migration_type') unset($data[$key]); 
       }

       return $data;
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it works only when direct called on model. If I am using some other functions, like `where`, before `get` or `first` methods, it just skips my overridden method.
What would be the right way to do this and should I put this code within model?

My question is not duplicate as in the answer from mentioned question it is said:

> all queries made from Models extending your CustomModel will get this new methods

And I need to override those two functions only for specific model, not for each one in application as not all tables have `type` column. That's the reason why I have written them within model class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Override Get or Select from Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160539/laravel-5-override-get-or-select-from-eloquent)

Comment: I have checked this one, but the answer is not clear enough

Comment: My bet is that on the return parent::where(*****) you can put your own ->where(your condition to always check for)

Comment: @Djip can you explain it a little bit further in the answer please?

Comment: I guess this is where the [Repository pattern](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce) gets useful.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `$hidden = 'migration_type'`?

Comment: @piscator I am looking for all records but `$hidden = 'migration_type'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to override above mentioned methods to skip some database records.

Consider a global query scope on the model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#global-scopes

> Global scopes allow you to add constraints to all queries for a given model. Laravel's own soft delete functionality utilizes global scopes to only pull "non-deleted" models from the database. Writing your own global scopes can provide a convenient, easy way to make sure every query for a given model receives certain constraints.

Comment: @niksrb One thing to note: The global scopes won't be applied to any raw `DB::` calls, as those bypass the Eloquent model entirely. If you always use the model to build queries, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the where() method on the model returns a `QueryBuilder` instance where get() will return a `Collection` instance.

You should be able to override collection's default methods by adding a macro in it's place and can be done like so...

```
Collection::macro('toUpper', function () {
    return $this->map(function ($value) {
        return Str::upper($value);
    });
});
```

Extending the query builder instance is not so easy but a good tutorial exists [here](https://medium.com/@justin.park001/laravel-techniques-extending-the-query-builder-2f4aca7956a2) and involves overriding the application's default connection class, which is not great when it comes to future upgrades.

Answer (score -1):

Because after calling where you're dealing with the database builder and theses methods inside your model aren't being called .. about the issue you might overcome it by using `select` instead of `first` directly so will deal with the builder  ..

example:

```
SomeTable::select('col1','col2')->take(1)->get();
```

another thing overriding these kind of methods is not a good idea if you're working with other developer on the same project.

good luck

Comment: I am working with other developers, but this is just one model and we all need this change. The application is too big to change every single `get` to use `select` in it's query. I hope there is a way to do exactly what I need

Comment: ofcourse there is always a way my friend .. but to keep things clean i suggest to change type of this model from  an eloquent model to sql object and accept the query builder inside your class and use `__call ` magic method to map calling of get or first to a customized method while you're getting the benefits of the query builder